# Multiple GPUs, but the same PCI bus id

Tags: tensorflow

Here is a simple script I wrote to utilize multiple GPUs:

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import os
files = ['data_S3_total_0.csv', 'data_S3_total_1.csv', 'data_S3_total_2.csv', 'data_S3_total_3.csv']
i = 0 
pids=set()
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
process0 = Popen(['python', 'rnn_5_dse_gpu.py', files[i]] )

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
process1 = Popen(['python', 'rnn_5_dse_gpu.py', files[i+1]] )

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '2'
process2 = Popen(['python', 'rnn_5_dse_gpu.py', files[i+2]] )

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '3'
process3 = Popen(['python', 'rnn_5_dse_gpu.py', files[i+3]] )

pids.add(process0.pid)
pids.add(process1.pid)
pids.add(process2.pid)
pids.add(process3.pid)

pid,retval=os.wait()
```

Basically, creating a separate process for each graph-gpu combination.I am doing it like this, because my models are completely independent. When I utilize a single GPU, my process completes in `23 seconds`, but with all the four processes, the completion time is `42 seconds`. In my TF graph, I am using `with tf.device("/gpu:0")`. Could someone please tell me why this overhead is there or how to find out the cause of the overhead?

One observation:

For all the 4 GPUs, Tensorflow shows `pciBusID 0000:0e:00.0`. But, when I do `lspci | grep K80`, I get

```
0e:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
0f:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
86:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
87:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK210GL [Tesla K80] (rev a1)
```

They all have different PCI bus ids as per the system. So, why is Tensorflow showing the same PCI bus ids for all the GPUs? Could that be the bottleneck?

Comment: probably this https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/16

Comment: Are you actually using all 4 gpus? (try nvidia-smi on a long-running computation). Also CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID is recommended

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: nvidia-smi shows only GPU0 being used. Four processes, but only a single GPU. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what if you set `CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER` and exclude GPU0 from the list of visible devices, will it still be used? Sounds like something's weird with your CUDA setup. Is this Azure? Their K80 machines are a bit wonky